# Samba Share Regularly Hangs for Win 10 Client

Tags: linux, samba, hang

I'm running samba 4.77 on Fedora 27 with Kernel 4.16.12.
I've got a fairly basic samba config, which I have posted below.
I use Windows 10 clients. This problem only ever
seems to happen on my samba share and I'm hoping that someone will be able
to help.

From time to time, but more often than not, Windows Explorer hangs for a
long time (10-20 minutes) when browsing my file share. Often I've right
clicked on a file and am trying to use the "Open With" menu. Before the
sub menu even opens Explorer will hang and be non-responsive. I've even
restarted Samba during this which does not fix it. Often this can happen
immediately just after a Windows reboot. The latest episode went like
this:

```
11:31 PC starts up Windows 10
11:32 click the  "Open with" menu. Windows Explorer actually dies this
time and restarts itself.
11:34 Explorer very slow to give me control over any of the "View" options
(details, icon, list etc)
11:34:45 Right click "Open with" and get the (Not Responding) problem
11:51:45 It responds
```

I just happened to be collecting a Tcpdump for this Windows client on port
445 for the duration of the incident.
This packet capture is available here:
 http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/smb.fails.tcpdump

Is anyone able to help?

```
-----------------smb.conf---------------------

[global]
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   writeable = yes
   server string = GW Samba Server %v
   admin users = mjurgens, vivian, jessica, jasmine, justin, julia
   workgroup = HOME
   hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24
192.168.3.0/24 192.168.4.0/24 192.168.10.0/24
   security = user
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   unix extensions = no
   load printers = no
   wide links = yes
   kernel oplocks = yes

   # needed for DDWRT routers
   ntlm auth = yes

[shared]
        path = /export/shared
        create mask = 0775
        comment = Shared
        valid users = @family playontv
```

Comment: I think a DDWRT router has not enough CPU and memory for sharing an external disk via USB for 6 people over wifi. Too many things to go wrong. Am I off in my guess? It would help you if you could describe the server hardware, what type of files are shared, and what are your wifi capabilities. e.g. you are not giving enough data of your setup. The tcpdump is probably a symptom and not a cause, most probably a waste of time looking at it. You usually only resort to low-level analysis after exhausting all other avenues of investigation and ruling them out, not before.

Comment: Sorry, I stated the some info about the software version(s) and linux distribution. You can't run those on a DDWRT router. To be clear this is running on a PC with an Intel Core  i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz with 16GB of RAM. SSDs for OS and Swap. This is connected via 1GBit ethernet cable to the PCs where I experience the hang
I share all sorts of generic files, images etc.